# Yii2 internationalization

Tags: php, yii2

My config is :

```
'language' => 'uz-UZ',
    'sourceLanguage' => 'ru-RU',
    'components' => [

        'i18n' => [
            'translations' => [
                'app*' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'basePath' => '@app/translations',
                    'sourceLanguage' => 'uz-UZ',
                    'fileMap' => [
                        'app' => 'app.php',
                        // 'app/error' => 'error.php',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

My @app/translations/uz-UZ/app.php :

```
<?php

return [
    'Все категории' => 'Kategoriyalar',
    'Salom' => 'Xayr'
]

?>
```

But in a view when Yii::$app->language = 'uz'  `<?= Y::t('app', 'Salom')?>` this echos 'Xayr', but  `<?= Y::t('app', 'Все категории')?>` still echos 'Все категории'. I wonder why cyrilic to lotin not working

Comment: can you remove the `source language` from the `app*` array and try once as from the docs you don't need it there, and source language is kept `en-US` **recommended** by docs **"It is recommended that you keep this default value unchanged. Usually it is much easier to find people who can translate from "English to other languages" than from "non-English to non-English"."**